# SharePoint migration. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, error, migration

I try to migrate my sharepoint library from on-premise SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online.
I do this by folowing SharePoint Online deployment advisor instructions.

I did this successfully:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://contosoweb/sites/project01 -Path C:\migration\Project01Library -ItemUrl "Shared Documents" -NoFileCompression
```

I created an user mapping CSV file.
It looks like:

```
OnPremSID,UPN,isGroup
s-1-5-21-79778582-742657681-665348310-13225,tan@contoso.com,False
s-1-5-21-79778582-742657681-665348310-11185,ANad@contoso.com,False
s-1-5-21-79778582-742657681-665348310-13306,otsap@contoso.com,False
```

After that I defined variables and tried to do this:

```
$finalPackages = ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage -ParallelImport -SourceFilesPath $sourceFiles -SourcePackagePath $sourcePackage -OutputPackagePath $targetPackage -Credentials $cred -TargetWebUrl $targetWeb -NoAzureADLookup -TargetDocumentLibraryPath $targetDocLib  -UserMappingFile $userMapFile
```

But I got an error:

```
ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage : Object reference not set to an
instance of an object.
At line:1 char:18
+ $finalPackages = ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage -ParallelImport
-SourceFi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargete
   dPackage], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Online.S
   harePoint.PowerShell.ConvertToMigrationPackage
```

How to fix it?
 I have diferent domain in SharePoint online and on-premise SharePoint. Should be usernames in the mapping csv file from on-premise SharePoint or SharePoint online domain (well, the error is the same)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate sharepoint library from on-premise SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online, you can refer to [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2015/07/18/using-windows-powershell-cmdlets-for-sharepoint-online-o365spo-migration/) article.

About this error, you can check if it has any detail error message in the ULS log.

You can refer to the same issue in [this](https://www.messageops.com/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-when-running-microsoft-online-powershell-commands/) article.

Answer (score 1):

In such scenarios, I would suggest using [SharePoint Migration Tool](https://debug.to/34/sharepoint-migration-tool) which supports `SharePoint 2013`, and it is a simple and fast solution to help you migrate content from on-premises SharePoint Server sites and file shares to SharePoint, OneDrive, and Microsoft Teams in Office 365.

> Read more at How to use [SharePoint Migration Tool](https://debug.to/34/sharepoint-migration-tool)

Regarding your issue, try to change the site collection administrator of this site as mentioned at [Sharepoint online - ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-convertto/ee7cebb2-cb47-4d59-b41f-84eabad38a85)